# epoll - is EPOLLET prone to race conditions?

Tags: linux, sockets, epoll, epollet

1. Process B epolls on the pipe (EPOLLIN|EPOLLET).
2. Process A writes 1KiB in pipe.
3. Process B wakes up.
4. Process B reads 1KiB from the pipe.
5. Process A writes 1KiB in pipe.
6. Process B epolls on the pipe.

The state of the pipe does not change during epoll, but has changed since the last read. Will process B wake up again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding from the FAQ (Q9) in http://linux.die.net/man/4/epoll is that you will get another event in step 6 (assuming that you can guarantee that step 5 really happens after step 4 and the pipe is empty after step 4).

Having said that, you might get more events than guaranteed (but you have to be careful only to rely on documented behavior) - see http://cmeerw.org/blog/753.html#753 and http://cmeerw.org/blog/750.html#750

Comment: I always read until E{AGAIN,WOULDBLOCK} so yes, I know 5 happens after 6.

Answer (score 1):

While it's true that the kernel wakes up on step 6, that is not what's documented by the manual page. The use case you provide does not conform to how `EPOLLET` is supposed to be used.

According to the documentation, step 6 should be "read from the FD". The only time you are supposed to poll from the FD is after you tried to read and got `EAGAIN`.

See also: [What is the use case for EPOLLET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46633433/what-is-the-use-case-for-epollet)